# Principal Covariate Regression (PCovR) in high dimensional settings

Tags: r, machine-learning

I would like to use Principal Covariate Regression in high-dimensional settings, where I have more explanatory variables (J) than observations (N). I came across the R-package "PCovR" (see CRAN-R package [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PCovR/PCovR.pdf), and Journal of Statistical Software article [here](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v065i08/v65i08.pdf)). This package does an excellent job in low-dimensional settings.

However, the package fails in high dimensional settings. To encounter the problem in high dimensions, you may run the following (minimum viable example) code:

```
# Load package
library(PCovR)    

# Fix random number generator
set.seed(1)

# Generate X: random standard normal matrix with J=200 explanatory variables and N=100 observations
x <- matrix(nrom(n=20000, mean=0, sd=1), nrow=100, ncol=200); dim(x)

# Generate Y: random standard normal vector with N=100 observations
y <- rnorm(n=100, mean=0, sd=1)  

# Run PCovR
pcovr.fit <- pcovr(X=x, Y=y, modsel="seq")
```

This gives the following error,

```
R> Error in Vminc[k] = which.min(A[, k]) : replacement has length zero
```

To tune the parameters *R* (number of components) and *alpha* (weighting parameter)  the package comes with a fast sequential model estimation option based on maximum-likelihood ("modsel=seq") and a computationally demanding simultaneous estimation based on grid-search cross-validation ("modsel=sim").

Source of the problem in higher dimensions is that the ratio-argument (that is by default computed with the ErrorRatio function if "modsel=seq") can clearly no longer be determined as a linear regression is performed in the ErrorRatio function. A feasible but sub-optimal solution is to use the simultaneous procedure with pre-specification of the ratio-argument (as it will not be used in the simultaneous procedure),

```
pcovr.fit <- pcovr(X=x, Y=y, modsel="sim", ratio=1)
```

But this is computationally extremely demanding. Any ideas, hints or suggestions how I may run PCovR in high-dimensional settings?

Answer (score 1):

An update of the package (version 2.7) has been released on CRAN earlier this week. In this newer version, the parameter "ratio" equals 1 by default in high-dimensional settings. Of course, other ratio's can be requested as well, but will lead to tiny changes in the obtained alpha value only in case of standardized data with 200 predictors (*J*) and only 1 criterion (*K*), as the maximum likelihood alpha is obtained with the following formula (for standardized data):

```
alpha <- J/(J+K*ratio)
```

Another way to go could be to search for another proxy of the error variances of your data, but in this specific situation, you will probably end up with an alpha value around .99 anyway.
It could be interesting, though, to investigate the impact of choosing another alpha value on the obtained solution.